# TikZ setting the edge of a path to horizontal rather than in=0 out=180 or vice versa

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

```
\path[->] (A) edge [out=180, in=0] (B);
```

This path is written quite often in my document.
Sometimes I find myself changing it to:

```
\path[->] (B) edge [out=0, in=180] (A);
```

I do not want to touch the `->` property for consistance sake.
But I would love to write something like:

```
\path[->] (B) edge [inout = horizontal] (A);
```

How can I achieve the implied effect?

---

**EDIT:**

Clarification:
I want those two paths to be the same path without manually changing the input output angles.

```
\path[-] (B) edge [inout = horizontal] (A);
\path[-] (A) edge [inout = horizontal] (B);
```

Here is a miniexample that illustrates the question better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node (B) at (3,2) {B};

    \node (C) at (3,0) {C};
    \node (D) at (6,2) {D};

    \path[-] (B) edge [out=0, in=180] (A); %not desired - longer path
    \path[-] (A) edge [out=0, in=180] (B); %desired path - shorter path

    %\path[-] (C) edge [inout = automagic] (D); %desired path - shorter path
    %\path[-] (D) edge [inout = automagic] (C); %desired path - shorter path 
    \path[-, ultra thick, red] (C) edge [out=0, in=180] (D); %desired result of [inout = automagic]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I provide three styles:

- **the `curve -` style that produces a “horizontal” curve** (the in and out direction are 0 and 180),
- the `curve |` style that produces a “vertical” curve (the in and out direction are 90 and 270),
- the underlying `curve +` style that, if used directly, decides on its own whether a “vertical” or “horizontal” curve shall be used.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  curve +/.default=2,
  curve +/.style={
    to path={
      \pgfextra
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztostart)\relax
        \pgf@xa\pgf@x
        \pgf@ya\pgf@y
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztotarget)\relax
        \ifnum#1=2
          \pgfmathifthenelse{abs(\pgf@xa-\pgf@x)<abs(\pgf@ya-\pgf@y)}{0}{1}% 0 = ver
                                                                           % 1 = hor
        \else
          \def\pgfmathresult{#1}%
        \fi
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
          \ifdim\pgf@ya<\pgf@y
            \def\tikz@to@out{90}\def\tikz@to@in{270}%
          \else
            \def\tikz@to@out{270}\def\tikz@to@in{90}%
          \fi
        \else
          \ifdim\pgf@xa<\pgf@x
            \def\tikz@to@out{0}\def\tikz@to@in{180}%
          \else
            \def\tikz@to@out{180}\def\tikz@to@in{0}%
          \fi
        \fi
      \endpgfextra
      \tikz@to@curve@path
    }
  },
  curve -/.style={curve +=1},
  curve |/.style={curve +=0},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\foreach \a in {0,2,...,359}{% Warning: Will typeset 180 pages!
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (-2.2,-2.2) rectangle (2.2,2.2);
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (\a:2cm) {B};
\path[->] (A) edge [black!50, curve |] (B)
              edge [black!50, curve -] (B)
              edge [black,    curve +] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can create your custom `.is choice` family. It will also complain if you mistype, or use an undesignated option that doesn't belong to the choice family which is helpful to debug.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{inout/.is choice,
inout/horizo/.style={in=180,out=0},
inout/horizorev/.style={out=180,in=0}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (3,2) {B};
\node (C) at (3,-2) {C};
\path[->] (A) edge [inout=horizo] (B);
\path[->] (A) edge [inout=horizorev] (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the answer, however i would like tikz to make that choice for me. It should always prefere the nearest connection over the further away connextion.

Comment: @Johannes So you don't want to write `[inout = horizontal]` at all but only `inout` since the option would be redundant if things are automated.  Am I right?

Comment: i am ok with writing `[inout = horizontal]`. if that causes the `\path[->] (A) edge [in=180,out=0] (B);` and `\path[->] (B) edge [in=0,out=180] (A);`. i want TikZ to pick the shorter path for me regardless of my input. The above option is a shorthand for the numbers but does not save me creating errors during my refactorings.

Comment: @Johannes Should the choice whether the connection is made horizontal (0/180) or vertical (90/270) be made by TikZ, too?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel no, thats why i suggested using the key horizontal. The idea is to use math to determine what is "best", where best would be case 1 if leftside.X smaller rigthside.X and case 2 otherwise. My usecase does not feature points that are so close that tex would be required to create a vertical connetion.